# Can we store use html5 local storage on curl request

Tags: php, curl, browser, local-storage

It seems like a dump question but i'm searching for all the possibilties.

**My Question**

A page is coded to store data on local storage, the data get saved on visiting the page directly on browser. When i use curl to access that page whether the same thing will happen? if not is there any way to make it happen.

I'm searching every possibility to make it happen, if anyone help me on this it will be very helpful, Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work like this, i had a similar problem, so this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061535/how-to-cache-api-response-using-curl-based-on-returned-etag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Local storage is dependent on the browser supporting HTML 5. Since CURL isn't a browser, it doesn't support local storage like this.